# How to call a function in a function with javascript small explanation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a beginner in java script a trying a little program that parse data from a text file. In order to create a filter on a particular date i have made a function to get the date  from and to that the user have enter. And the date a have to compare if it is in the range is in the text file, this date also i got it. But now i don't want to re-write the function "getAllFilesFromFolder" found in the code below, this function must be executed in all case but if i click on the button filter by by date it must read on the files with the date in range given by the user. Can someone give me an explanation on how to do it. i have tried the code below.

```
function getdate(){
      var dateStart = new Date($('#dateStart').val()).getTime();
      var dateEnd = new Date($('#dateEnd').val()).getTime();
      //if(!testDate){var testDate = new Date(2014, 05, 02).getTime();}
      var testDate = new Date(2014, 05, 02).getTime();
      if (dateStart <= testDate && testDate <= dateEnd) {
          alert('IN');
          //Here filter the files with the date 
      }else{
         alert('OUT');
         //Here no new to read and parse the file beacause it is out of range 
      }

    }

//Parse folder and file to get the required files
function getAllFilesFromFolder(folder){
  //Parsing the given folder the result which is return is kept in an array
  var test = fse.readdirSync(folder);
  //Going through the array 
  for(var n=0; test[n]; n++){
    var stats = fs.lstatSync(folder+"\\"+test[n]);
    if(stats && stats.isDirectory()){
      getAllFilesFromFolder(folder+"\\"+test[n]);
      var path = folder+"\\"+test[n]+"<br />";
      }else{  
        var path = folder+"\\"+test[n];
        //Regex on the file to be taken
        var pattern = /^(PM)[0-9]{5}[_](xam)[_](pmbok5th)[_](pmp)[_](v92)(.txt)$/;
        var parent = folder+"\\";
        var file = test[n];
        var load = pattern.test(file); 
        //Split on file to get the "id user"
        identifiant = file.split('_');
        //Test the regex on file name "PM*_xam_pmbok5th_pmp_v92.txt" 
        if(load == true){
          var read = fse.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
          var suspendDate = read.lastIndexOf('xam/');
          var wantedDate = read.slice(suspendDate);
          info = wantedDate.split('/');
          var suspendData = read.lastIndexOf('/DB');
          var suspendData = wantedDate.lastIndexOf('/DB');
          var wantedData = wantedDate.slice(suspendData);
          var db_response = wantedData.split(".");
          var all_response = db_response[0].split(":");  


          if(typeof(info[2]) != "undefined" && all_response != "undefined"){
            var response = all_response[1].split("|");
            //Parsing the array response to find the "id" here id of the question and the "ans" here answer of the question "R" or "W"
            for(var p = 0; p < response.length; p++){
              //Test if result exist we increment if not it is generate with the function initResp
              if(typeof(response[p]) != "undefined"){
                var id = response[p].slice(0,6);
                var ans = response[p].slice(-1);
                if (question[id]) {
                  question[id][ans] += 1;
                  } else {
                    var results = initResp(ans);
                    question[id] = results;
                    }; 

                } else {
                  } 
            }
          } else {
            //$("#results1").append("<strong>La session est vide</strong><br>");
            }
          i++;
      } 
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I have no idea what is your question. Could you simplify the problem you are having? Also how is the file reading supposed to happen in javascript, what is the variable fse?

Comment: Fse is file system extra it is a module in node_js. The file reading happen in the condition if(load == true). getAllFilesFolder must be execuuted at least one time beacause if the user don't want a date filter and get all the result it must be possible also. My question is me i want to create a date filter, so i create a button that call a function getdate that compare a date in a range of date, now a want to put that function in the function getAllFilesFromFolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. See the code below for more information

```
function rangeDate(testDate){
  var dateStart = new Date($('#dateStart').val()).getTime();
  var dateEnd = new Date($('#dateEnd').val()).getTime();
  if (dateStart <= testDate && testDate <= dateEnd) {
      date = true;
      return date;
  }else{
      date = false;
      return date;
  }

}
function getAllFilesFromFolder(folder)/*, useDate*/{
  //Parsing the given folder the result which is return is kept in an array
  var test = fse.readdirSync(folder);
  //Going through the array 
  for(var n=0; test[n]; n++){
    var stats = fs.lstatSync(folder+"\\"+test[n]);
    if(stats && stats.isDirectory()){
      getAllFilesFromFolder(folder+"\\"+test[n]);
      var path = folder+"\\"+test[n]+"<br />";
      }else{  
        var path = folder+"\\"+test[n];
        //Regex on the file to be taken
        var pattern = /^(PM)[0-9]{5}[_](xam)[_](pmbok5th)[_](pmp)[_](v92)(.txt)$/;
        var parent = folder+"\\";
        var file = test[n];
        var load = pattern.test(file); 
        //Split on file to get the "id user"
        identifiant = file.split('_');
        //Test the regex on file name "PM*_xam_pmbok5th_pmp_v92.txt" 
        if(load == true){
          var read = fse.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
          var suspendDate = read.lastIndexOf('xam/');
          var wantedDate = read.slice(suspendDate);
          var info = wantedDate.split('/');
          testDate = new Date(info[4]).getTime();
          rangeDate(testDate);
          if(date == true){
            var suspendData = read.lastIndexOf('/DB');
            var suspendData = wantedDate.lastIndexOf('/DB');
            var wantedData = wantedDate.slice(suspendData);
            var db_response = wantedData.split(".");
            var all_response = db_response[0].split(":");  
            if(typeof(info[2]) != "undefined" && all_response != "undefined"){
              var response = all_response[1].split("|");
              //Parsing the array response to find the "id" here id of the question and the "ans" here answer of the question "R" or "W"
              for(var p = 0; p < response.length; p++){
                //Test if result exist we increment if not it is generate with the function initResp
                if(typeof(response[p]) != "undefined"){
                  var id = response[p].slice(0,6);
                  var ans = response[p].slice(-1);
                  if (question[id]) {
                    question[id][ans] += 1;
                    } else {
                      var results = initResp(ans);
                      question[id] = results;
                      }; 

                  } else {
                    } 
              }
            } else {
              //$("#results1").append("<strong>La session est vide</strong><br>");
              }
            i++;
          }else{

          }

      } 
    }
  }


};
```